Why can't my Mac's Terminal find the xlwings command?
I installed xlwings with pip3. It says:
% pip3 install xlwings
Requirement already satisfied: xlwings in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (0.33.4)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=2.0.0 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from xlwings) (6.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appscript>=1.0.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from xlwings) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=4.7.1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from appscript>=1.0.1->xlwings) (5.3.0)

I'm not sure what to expect but I don't see any problems.
When I type xlwings in a macOS Terminal window, it says:
% xlwings
zsh: command not found: xlwings

It should print a list of xlwings' commands.
In order to verify the installation, I entered the following program in a main.py file in Pycharm:
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('data.xlsx')
wks = xw.sheets
print("Available sheets :\n", wks)
ws = wks[0]
val = ws.range("A1").value
print("A value in sheet1 :", val)

Then I opened Excel, created a new workbook, entered "zyd" in Sheet1!A1, saved it as data.xlsx in the same folder as the Pycharm project and ran the Python program. It compiled and ran without complaint and displayed:
Available sheets :
 Sheets([<Sheet [data.xlsx]Sheet1>])
A value in sheet1 : zyd

so I think the package is installed correctly.
What else do I need to do to make the Terminal command work?
My configuration is:
iMac M1
macOS Sequoia 15.1.1 with all updates
Python 3.12.0
Edit 12/11/2024:
I don't know much about the macOS/Unix file structure or where the xlwings executable should be. My PATH looks like:
% echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
I entered the Terminal command:
sudo find / -name 'xlwings*.*' > ~/Desktop/find.txt

Then I opened find.txt in Excel and filtered out trash, time machine, and pycharm directories. The only thing left was the xlwings folder in Python3.12/site-packages. I don't see a xlwings executable anywhere.

What happens when you run python3 -m xlwings in your shell?

Are the xlwings binaries in the path? Seems like a standard can't find/run a file if there is no path to it problem. Does MACOS support the command which ? If so does that show the path to the binary

When you install an executable program with pip, it is typically placed in ~/.local/bin.  Is that directory on your path?

% python3 -m xlwings
/usr/local/bin/python3: No module named xlwings.main; 'xlwings' is a package and cannot be directly executed

% which xlwings
xlwings not found

I don't think there's a ~/.local/bin directory.  % ls -a ~
.
..
.CFUserTextEncoding
.DS_Store
.Trash
.bash_profile
.config
.cups
.dropbox
.idlerc
.lesshst
.matplotlib
.python_history
.ssh
.swiftpm
.tcshrc
.xonshrc
.zsh_history
.zsh_sessions

The xlwings binary won't be called xlwings.exe like on Windows, so you should probably search like this sudo find / -name 'xlwings' > ~/Desktop/find.txt 2> /dev/null

Sidenote: don't install things globally (current Python won't even let you do that anymore without explicitly saying you're okay with potentially breaking system packages): use a virtual environment for your project and simply install things there (using python3 -m pip3 install). That way you're guaranteed that what you installed will be found while your virtual environment is active.

Appending /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin to the PATH fixed the problem. I'm surprised the Installation section at xlwings.org doesn't say to do this (sigh).

This is literally what Python virtual environments do for you, so instead of manually hacking your system or user level PATH vars to solve a problem that current Python doesn't even have anymore (because you can't install packages globally anymore without jumping through hoops), just start using Python venvs.
